# AspectJ - pointcut to capture all WebElements annotated with @FindBy

Tags: java, selenium, aop, aspectj, page-factory

My test framework uses selenium's PageFactory and Lambok. I want to write an aspect to capture all the web elements that a test flow comes across while running.

A typical page looks like:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyCustomPage {

    @Inject
    private IWebDriverSet driverSet;

    @Getter
    @FindBy(id = PAGE_ROOT)
    private WebElement root;

    @FindAll({
            @FindBy(css = FOOT_BAR),
            @FindBy(css = FOOT_BAR_B)
    })
    private WebElement navBar;
}
```

@FindBy determines the webelement that tests deal with. There are 50 of such pages.

The webElement fields are instantiated (assigned with a WebElement instance corresponding to the value in @FindBy) when the page is instantiated using the PageFactory.

I would like to capture these webElements that are annotated with @FindBy/@FindAll as soon as they are instantiated.
I dont want to write a separate pointcut for every page class.
How to do that?

Comment: IMO no selenium way of doing it, only good old java reflection. Even then you will have to pass list of classes to analyze. Or rewrite FindBy to have some logging in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture"? Just logging? You can extend the DefaultFieldDecorator and add code to the decorate() method. Then pass in the new decorator class to the PageFactory static initElements(FieldDecorator decorator, java.lang.Object page)method  to initialize the pageobjects. This code will run for each webelement with the findby annotation that needs to beproxied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since value of a WebElement assigned via reflection you can't intercept that with set() pointcut designator. But you can track all calls to `java.lang.reflect.Field.set`

```
    @After("call(* java.lang.reflect.Field.set(..)) && args(obj, value) && target(target)")
    public void webelementInit(JoinPoint jp, Object obj, Object value, Field target) {
        //obj - instance of a class (page object) that declares current field
        //value - new field value (instantiated WebElement)
        //field - current field
        //you can filter calls to the fields you need by matching target.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName() with page object's package
        //for example:
        //if(target.getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName().contains("com.example.pageobjects")) {
            //do stuff
        //}
    }
```

In that case you need to define rt.jar in dependencies section in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>java</groupId>
            <artifactId>jre-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

and in weaveDependencies section of aspectj-maven-plugin

```
<weaveDependencies>
    <weaveDependency>
        <groupId>java</groupId>
        <artifactId>jre-runtime</artifactId>
    </weaveDependency>
...
</weaveDependencies>
```